# Rails Max possible value for ActiveRecord id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I wonder what max value can id attribute of ActiveRecord hold, is it somewhat related to integer max value of ruby ? 
Any leads ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm quite certain you will hit the database limit long before you'll hit Ruby's limit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the datatype. By default rails select id type `int(11)`. Here is the maximum limits:

- **int:** 2^31-1 (2,147,483,647)
- **bigint:** 2^63-1 (9,223,372,036,854,775,807)

If you use `bigint`, you're unlikely to ever overflow.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the limit of the corresponding column in the database.

Ruby's fixnum's have an upper limit (`2**30 - 1` on 32bit platforms, `2**62 - 1` on 64 bit), but ruby will transparently switch to bignums, which have unlimited precision.